# Kill user session if from unknown source

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, kill, finger

I would like to kill ssh connections to my server if they are from a particular 'office'

Any ideas how I would do this without using ip-tables?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use what are called "TCP wrappers", the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files to restrict access. For example, you can add the line:

```
sshd: sammy.badguy.net
```

to `/etc/hosts.deny`.

You generally don't need to restart networking of services for changes to `/etc/hosts.deny` to take effect, however, you should test after making any changes, especially if made changes remotely while logged in via SSH.

You can find a more complete guide to controlling SSH access with TCP wrappers [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/87).

You can also read

```
man hosts.deny
```